# UI Testing with XCUI

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I'm trying for unit testing of view controllers in xCode 8. I'm able to record, assert and run it successfully using XCUI. But I want to test particular view controller independently.

Like there are 4 controllers A,B,C and D in sequence    (A->B->C->D). I want to directly launch C controller and test it independently.

I'm able to test in this way i.e. default XCUIApplication will open A controller then click on something you will go to B Controller and then click on button in B will take you to C Controller. Then you can test it out. But I don't want in sequence. I want to directly test C controller.

Can you please help if anyone else has done same kind of job. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCUITest with Xcode

If you using UITestCase now, you can't directly open D controller

everytime should do sequence (A->B->C->D) because all test case spec cause app launching espectially SignIn, SignOut should be needed for UITest every time

supplementary way to use XCUI Test for testCase

provide A, B, C's sequence function as protocol for minimizing duplicated code

ex) define Login protocol

```
protocol Loginable {
    var app: XCUIApplication! { get }
    func login()
}

extension Loginable {
    func login() {
        //do login ... typting textfield , tap login button
    }
}
```

extend your A,B,C,D UITestCase using Loginable to remove duplicated code (because every D uitest case should be logined in example)

make extension for sequence function to reuse every case

alternative solution is

use [KIF Functional Test framework](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF)

KIF can test UITest based on XCTest instead XCUITest

KIF can access your class like unit test that means

you can show your D ViewController to window (set rootViewController directly) and test KIF UItest function

ex) KIF

```
import XCTest

@testable import YourApp
class DViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut: DViewController!
    var window: UIWindow!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        window = appDelegate.window

        sut = //Initialize your D ViewController
        window.rootViewController = sut
        RunLoop.current.run(until: Date()) // cause viewDidLoad
    }

    func testSomeCase() {
        tester().tapView(withAccessibilityIdentifier: "someIdentifier")
        ...
    }
}
```

KIF can directly launch D controller setting rootViewController to window

Comment: thanks Cruz. Your solution looks to be very helpful. I'll implement it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GopeshGupta 

Answer (score 1):

Since XCUI tests are integration tests, you have to follow the flow `(A->B->C->D)`. You can instead do the necessary steps (e.g. logging in) and then create deep links for your app.
Deep linking is a technique that allows an app to be opened to a specific UI or resource, in response to some external event.
As a result you don't have to repeat the sequence of `(A->B->C->D)` and instead can implement a deep link that directly takes you to D. This way the particular test only checks for the functionality of D view controller.
Following are some useful links:

[urbanairship](https://docs.urbanairship.com/tutorials/ea-ios-deep-linking/)    [kamyacademy](http://www.kamyacademy.com/en/how-to-debug-deep-linking-in-ios/)    [medium.com](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272)